# Hbase vs Cassandra vs Kafka for high resolution time series data storage

Tags: cassandra, hbase, apache-kafka

Between Hbase, Cassandra and Kafka, what are the pros and cons of using either technology for for high resolution (s or even ms) time series data storage?

Comment: Can you comment on what, if anything, you need to do with that data?

Comment: Visualize them and also analyze them both realtime and historical

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all - **Kafka, AFAIK, is not a storage system** but rather a messaging platform you can use to send the time series events to a system that will process and store that information.

Second of all - it all depends on how would you like to aggregate, query and fetch the data. As with most NoSQL databases those questions are crucial before you will even consider to move forward.

Third - there are two solutions to store time series data built on top of both HBase and Cassandra, namely [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net) and [KairosDB](https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/). Both pretty well known, both should be able to store events with high resolution (seconds or milliseconds). Or, alternatively, you might want to take a look at [Druid](http://druid.io), but that's a little bit different approach to the problem...

Overall, I would suggest KairosDB - it's proved to be a great performant for us storing TB of time series data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Really my question is that what does it depend on? Can you shed some lights on how hbase and Cassandra differ based on aggregate, query or fetching? Also why did you select  KairosDB over OpenTSDB?

Comment: The reason for us to go with Kairos was mainly Cassandra - we know it well, it's reliable and pretty well documented. The symmetric architecture enabled us to scale the cluster easily while we can still maintain a great data consistency. The setup of a really complex C* cluster is way, way easier than it is with HBase. 
KairsoDB and OpenTSDB are very similar in the design, so that was not the main reason for us to start using one over another. Cassandra was that reason, really...

Comment: Is Cassandra eventual consistency model any concern for real time visualization? Also, can you please share your current performance metrics and your cluster spec?

Comment: Eventual consistency is something that you can control easily, so no problem there. 
As far as metrics - this stuff is confidential in our company, we do not share any information about current operations. So cannot help you there. But KairosDB have a nice community and you can ask for something like that on Google Groups - surely there will be a non-german company that is more open...

Comment: "Kafka, AFAIK, is not a storage system" not entirely true. Retention is configurable.

Comment: @liammclennan - retention of message or solid storage for messages in transit is still not a storage engine :-)

Comment: Though debatably...if the entire purpose of the storage engine is to store a message temporarily while in flight and then remove it...it "kinda is" right?